# possible to copy s3 file and change its zip format while doing so?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to copy a s3 file elsewhere and replace the zip format from `.zip` to `.gz` so athena can read it.

Is there any option of doing so while running the s3 copy command or do I have to download the file, unzip, gzip and upload it?

I'm using something like this:

```
bucket=''
target=''
source=''
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.Object(bucket, target).copy_from('{}/{}'.format(bucket,source)
```

Comment: What is the problem with .gz? It should be supported by Athena. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/compression-formats.html

Comment: I want to convert from `zip` to `gzip` so it will be supported.

Comment: Got it - my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS **S3 can't re-pack** your files, as it is only object storage system, which any build-in re-formatting or re-packing capabilities for your object. You either have to download them to your local machine / EC2 instance, re-pack, and re-upload in correct format.

Depending on the number and size of the files, you may also consider using [S3 Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html) and use lambda function to execute re-packing of each zip file.